# Chromium: "display: list-item" - Works only after re-enter this rule

Tags: css, list, chromium

I have a navigator on my site, made of `<ul>` elements:

```
<div class="navigator">
    <ul>
        <li class="nav-item nav-parent nav-expanded">Category One
            <ul>
                <li class="nav-item nav-parent nav-collapsed">Subcategory One</li>
                <li class="nav-item nav-parent nav-collapsed">Subcategory Two</li>
                <li class="nav-item nav-parent nav-collapsed">Subcategory Three</li>
                <li class="nav-item nav-parent nav-expanded">Subcategory Four
                    <ul>
                        <li class="nav-item nav-expanded">Item 4-1</li>
                        <li class="nav-item nav-selected">Item 4-2</li>
                        <li class="nav-item nav-expanded">Item 4-3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item nav-parent nav-collapsed">Subcategory Five</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item nav-collapsed">Category Two</li>
        <li class="nav-item nav-collapsed">Category Three</li>
        <li class="nav-item nav-collapsed">Category Four</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Expanded and collapsed elements differ in a mark "+" or "-" made by following rules of css:

```
li.nav-expanded:before {
    content: "- ";
}
li.nav-collapsed:before {
    content: "+ ";
}
```

It looks fine in Firefox:

[image: http://img853.imageshack.us/img853/4889/selection002z.png]

But it looks weird in Chromium:

[image]

Why is this weird - because it fixes with strange action in `Developer tools`:
I choose `li.nav-item` element, change `display: list-item` to `display:inline` and back to `display:list-item`. And it looks fine.

I don't understand, how to fix this? Is this Chromium bug?

Comment: probably has something do with your caching. Clear your cache and try it again.

Comment: Can you list your chromium build version?

Comment: @MichaelRader, clearing cache didn't help.

Comment: @zethus, `14.0.835.202 (Developer Build 103287 Linux) Ubuntu 10.10`

Comment: check padding and margin in both browsers and apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<ul>` that are inside the `<li>` should be `display: list-item` too. So making:

```
li.nav-item ul, .navigator ul {
    display: list-item;
}
```

fixed the problem in Chromium.